# Efficiency when drawing an ImageView with rounded corners

Tags: android, graphics, android-custom-view

I have an `ImageView` subclass that I use to draw images with rounded corners.  The code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/73003), and is as follows:

```
public class ImageViewRoundedCorners extends ImageView {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getMeasuredWidth(),
                                                  getMeasuredHeight(),
                                                  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
        Canvas scaledCanvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        super.onDraw(scaledCanvas); 
        drawRoundedCornerBitmap(canvas, scaledBitmap, 
                                getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        scaledBitmap.recycle();
    }

    protected void drawRoundedCornerBitmap(Canvas outputCanvas, Bitmap input, int w, int h) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        mPaint.reset();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPath(mClipPath, mPaint);

        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, mPaint);

        outputCanvas.drawBitmap(output, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

With this code, the image is drawn with properly rounded corners.  To avoid the allocations on the first two lines of `drawRoundedCornerBitmap`, I want to draw directly to `outputCanvas`, which is the canvas originally passed to `onDraw`.  The new implementation looks like this:

```
protected void drawRoundedCornerBitmap(...) {
    mPaint.reset();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    outputCanvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    outputCanvas.drawPath(mClipPath, mPaint);

    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    outputCanvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, mPaint);
}
```

For some reason, this code seems to ignore the Porter-Duff mode, and instead just draws the image with normal (non-rounded) corners.  Why is this the case?  What is it about drawing to an intermediate `Bitmap` that makes the original code work?

Comment: did u find any solution for this... even i'm trying same thing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a drawable Romain Guy has done this for you. We are not a link factory but his blog post explains it quite extensively and provides an efficient way of doing this. [Rounded Corners](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/)

The real basic principle, is create a `BitmapShader` and attach it to a `Paint` object which draws in a custom `Drawable` that way you just apply that `Drawable` to the `ImageView`.

Using a drawable means that the Image is only painted to a canvas once, meaning that drawing the image is only done once, then all the ImageView does is just scale the drawable.

Comment: Isn't this sort of a pain when you have to scale that drawable in the imageView? The drawable is created, then stretched or cropped, which means your corners are going to look weird, no?

Comment: Remember the `ImageView` turns whatever you pass to it into a `Drawable`, provides its size, then calls `draw()` on the `Drawable`. By default if you had a BitmapDrawable it will of course just stretch it, as you pass a `RoundedBitmapDrawable` per-se, it will draw based on that implementation.